# Pusher is disconnect in some time and result in no real time messaging in iOS Application

Tags: iphone, ios, pusher

I am creating a chat application using Pusher library. connection is made correctly but when I  chat for about near about 10 minutes connection fail and vacated in debug console of pushe app account and result in no real time messaging any more. I have implemented delegate method but delegate method does not call when connection vacated.

For creating pusher client:

```
 client = [PTPusher pusherWithKey:@"XXXXXXXXXXXXXX" delegate:self encrypted:NO];

 client.reconnectAutomatically = YES;

 client.reconnectDelay = 30;

 [client connect];
```

Delegate Methods:

- (void)pusher:(PTPusher *)client1 connectionDidDisconnect:(PTPusherConnection *)connection
  {
  Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];

  if ([reachability currentReachabilityStatus] == NotReachable) {
      // there is no point in trying to reconnect at this point
      client1.reconnectAutomatically = NO;

  ```
  // start observing the reachability status to see when we come back online
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
   addObserver:self
   selector:@selector(reachabilityChanged:)
   name:kReachabilityChangedNotification
  ```

  object:reachability];

  ```
  [reachability startNotifier];
  ```

  }
  }
- (void)reachabilityChanged:(NSNotification *)note
  {
  Reachability *reachability = note.object;

  if ([reachability currentReachabilityStatus] != NotReachable) {
      // we seem to have some kind of network reachability, so try again
       //= <# get the pusher instance #>
      PTPusher *pusher = [PTPusher pusherWithKey:@"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" delegate:self encrypted:NO];

  ```
  [pusher connect];

  // we can stop observing reachability changes now
  ```

  //        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
  //        [reachability stopNotifier];

  ```
  // re-enable auto-reconnect
  pusher.reconnectAutomatically = YES;
  ```

  }
  }

Comment: Are you retaining `client` somehow?

Comment: @Ian I am not retaining client anywhere

Comment: That's probably the issue. Since you're not retaining the client, it's probably getting released and thus disconnecting. Try to associate it to a `strong` property.

Comment: I have use Strong property for client object but problem is still remain.

Comment: @Mukesh2421: Are you connected the pusher and get the notification from pusher.. I connected the pusher but I dont know how to proceed further..